# PHP form conflicting with... something.

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

If I have the following code before `</head>` the php form sends **but** the css crashes and doesn't display the dropdown menu.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If I don't have the code, the submit button refreshes the page if blank and never sends anything but the dropdown menu works. If any of the fields are filled, the submit button returns with 404.

**How can I keep both?**

Additional details:

- Wordpress CMS
- The JQuery script was inserted in a field for customized js in WP.

Comment: Can you post some other includes? How does the CSS 'crash'? Do you have multiple jquery includes?

Comment: What form? What do you mean by 'the css crashes'? We need to see the relevant code (in the question, not external links)

Comment: why u include online jquery library...instead download the jquery library and use that..

Comment: -1 @diEcho. That's poor advice.

Comment: Phils advice is the way to go, please post a SS or add more details about how your CSS is 'crashing'

Comment: @barfoon The CSS doesn't really crash but the dropdown menu doesn't show the mini arrow and is not triggered by mouseover.

Comment: @Bosworth99 In general its not a bad advice since sometimes CDNs can screw things up and create timeouts which practically render websites which are CDN dependent useless. That's the reason why most critical web services don't use external resources as critical components. Yes I know spreading requests across multiple domains is one of the major points in page speed optimization but sometimes using external resources is simply not an option.

Comment: @mu is too short The confirmation message and modernizr only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know `JS` is default, but try putting the `type="text/javascript"` in the `<script>` tag. Also, firebug for firefox has a NET tab that will most likely tell you what is going on. I would suggest if you can't figure it out by yourself, to post a screen shot of what is loading.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress can get finicky with manually embedded js and style embeds. The correct way to inject them is to `add_actions` to `init`, `print_scripts` and `print_sytles`. Add the following, or something like it to your `Functions.php`:

```
// register scripts 
if (! function_exists(register_scripts){
function register_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js');
    }  
}   
add_action('init', 'register_scripts');

//print the now registered scripts 
if (! function_exists(print_scripts){
function print_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }  
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'print_scripts');

// do the same for css 
if (! function_exists(print_styles){
function print_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'stylesheet', 'path to css'.stylesheet.css );  //bloginfo(url); or something like it to obtain your path
    wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet' );
    }  
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'print_styles');
```

Its a little more work, but ensures scripts and styles get inserted correctly, and at the same time wordpress chooses to do so...

I'm not positive if this is causing your issue, but its a great place to start.